# two forms on different pages connected to the same php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have these three pieces of code which are supposed to be 2 different forms that send the data to the php. But when I am done with filling in the second form the data of the first form is gone. I can't use 2 different php files because I have to send the data to planyo using file_get_contents.

1st file, testform 1:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testform 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" name="testform1">
        <label for="naam">naam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="naam"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form1">
        <input type="submit" value="form1">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd file, testform 2:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testform 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" name="testform2">
        <label for="achternaam">achternaam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="achternaam"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form2">
        <input type="submit" value="form2">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php file:

```
<?php
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";


switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'form1': 
    $firstname = $_POST['naam'];
    echo "form 1 gelukt";
    header("Location: http://localhost:8081/greenjoy/testform2.html");
    break;
    case 'form2':
    $lastname = $_POST['achternaam'];
    echo "form 2 gelukt";
    echo "$firstname" . "$lastname";
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: you're outputting before header in the first case.

Comment: the header is to redirect you to the second form

Comment: remove `echo "form 1 gelukt";`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Modify your files like this:

testform1.html: no change.
testform2.html, change it into a php file (testform2.phtml):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testform 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" name="testform2">
        <label for="achternaam">achternaam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="achternaam"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form2">
        <input type="hidden" name="naam" value="<?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="form2">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";


switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'form1': 
        $firstname = $_POST['naam'];
        echo "form 1 gelukt";
        header("Location: http://localhost:8081/greenjoy/testform2.html?firstname=$firstname");
        break;
    case 'form2':
        $firstname = $_POST['naam'];
        $lastname = $_POST['achternaam'];
        echo "form 2 gelukt";
        echo "$firstname" . "$lastname";
        break;
}
?>
```

- This demonstrate the concept, but you should add code to verify if $_GET['firstname'] is set (and react if not).
- The idea is to carry the firstname value with you when going to testform2.
- Ensure your application flow does not allow a user go to testform2 before going to testform1.  This could be done by: if $_GET['firstname'] is not set when calling testform2, redirect the user to testform1 automatically.
- Remember that each call to test.php is indendant of the other one.  This is why the value set when processing testform1 is not available in testform2.
- Another method that could be used is to set the value from testform1 into a session or a database and retrieve it when accessing testform2.  More complicated.
- Ask yourself if exposing the parameter to testform2 is a security risk or not.  If yes == use sessions or database!  If not, you can use what I propose.
- Another solution if you want to hide your $_GET values, you could encrypt the parameters.